# How Bulk insert in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert, bulkinsert

I have two similar tables in two databases. Person_Table1 in DB1 and Person_Table2 in DB2.
I want have a bulk insert from Person_Table1 in DB1 to Person_Table2 on DB2.

Column Names in both tabels is similar. Count of Column in both tables is equal also count of column is many. How can i have a bulk insert like fallowing query:

```
insert into DB2.dbo.Person_Table2 (*) (SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.Person_Table1 )
```

Comment: What you have is close, but you just need to specify the column list for the insert into as well as the select.  I.E

insert into DB2.dbo.Person_Table2 
(
 LastName
 ,FirstName
 ,MiddleName
) 
SELECT 
 LastName
 ,FirstName
 ,MiddleName
FROM DB1.dbo.Person_Table1

Comment: @Hiawatha Tiller I know it but my column count is many and i want use from Select * also i do this for many Tables

Comment: You can't use a * because the table definitions probably don't match plus it's bad habit to get into.  There are probably a variety of other problems like moving identity values or foreign key constraints from one database not matching in the other. Listing out the column names is the right approach.

Comment: If you are up for learning something new.  Try googling Sql Server Integration Services since what it sounds like you are doing is bulk moving of data from one system to another.  I don't know the frequency in which you are having to do these bulk moves (one time move, or maybe once a day) so SSIS may be over kill depending on your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always use explicit column names - just to be very clear and safe when doing such an INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.Person_Table2(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN) 
   SELECT Col1, Col2, ...., ColN
   FROM DB1.dbo.Person_Table1
```

That way, you could also e.g. replace one column in the target table with e.g. a constant value or the value of a SQL function (like `GETDATE()` or something)

```
INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.Person_Table2(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN, ModifyDate) 
   SELECT Col1, Col2, ...., ColN, GETDATE()
   FROM DB1.dbo.Person_Table1
```

Comment: I know it but my column count is many and i want use from `Select * ` also i do this for many Tables

Comment: @ehsanzeynali: I would **NOT** use `*` since that's always prone to errors and breaks when one of the table's structure changes for any reason... yes, it requires a bit of typing, but that extra effort is worth it!

Comment: is it mean not exist any solution for this operation?

Comment: @ehsanzeynali: the solution is to **explicitly spell out** all column names involved